# Get all full path of specific extension

Tags: python, filenames

I want to get full path of all files of specific `extension` inside root folder, this is what i have try (currently only file names without full path):

```
xmls = r'C:\xmls'

included_extensions = ['xml']
file_names = [fn for fn in os.listdir(xmls) if any(fn.endswith(ext) for ext in included_extensions)]
```

Comment: Do you also want to check recursively?

Comment: i will be glad to have the option if i want  (maybe to add some Boolean flag)